# How to preserve argument type of polymorphic function in return type

Tags: scala

Given a polymorphic function, how to match the polymorphic argument and return a value of the same type without resorting to explicit casts?

```
sealed trait Data
case class DString(s: String) extends Data
case class DInt(n: Int) extends Data

def double[D <: Data](d: D): D = d match {
  case DString(s) => DString(s ++ s)
  case DInt(n) => DInt(n + n)
}
```

This produces type mismatches (found `DString`/`DInt`, required `D`).
Why does the type system not accept this when the input type clearly equals the output type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a legitimate place to use method overloading:

```
def double(ds: DString) = DString(ds.s ++ ds.s)
def double(di: DInt) = DInt(di.n + di.n)
```

You can also use type classes:

```
abstract class DataDoubler[A <: Data] {
  def double(a: A): A
}

implicit object DStringDoubler extends DataDoubler[DString] {
  def double(ds: DString) = DString(ds.s ++ ds.s)
}

implicit object DIntDoubler extends DataDoubler[DInt] {
  def double(di: DInt) = DInt(di.n + di.n)
}

def double[A <: Data](a: A)(implicit dd: DataDoubler[A]): A = dd.double(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a reformulation of a problem that [pops up time and again on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=f%20bounded%20polymorphism%20scala), which is usually solved using F-bounded polymorphism. The only difference is that you want to preserve the type you're working on in a function that's not defined inside the trait.

So, what I'd do is move that `double` method inside the `Data` trait and use an abstract type member:

```
sealed trait Data {
  type Self <: Data
  def double: Self
}

case class DString(s: String) extends Data {
  type Self = DString
  def double = DString(s ++ s)
}

case class DInt(n: Int) extends Data {
  type Self = DInt
  def double = DInt(n + n)
}
```

Otherwise, I'm not aware of a solution.